# Correct method to check for a specific value in a Firebase Array

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a specific value exists in my Firebase database.

This is my current layout:

```
MYAPP
    |_______________users
    |                   |_____OshwYF72Jhd9bUw56W7d
    |                   |                   |
    |                   |                   |__username
    |                   |                   |__email            
    |                   |                   |__friends             
    |                   |                            |
    |                   |                            |__KbHy4293dYgVtT9pdoW
    |                   |                            |__PS8tgw53SnO892Jhweh
    |                   |                            |__Qufi83bdyg037D7RBif
    |                   |                            |__Gicuwy8r23ndoijdakr
    |                   |
    |                   |_____KbHy4293dYgVtT9pdoW
    |                   |_____PS8tgw53SnO892Jhweh
    |                   |_____Gicuwy8r23ndoijdakr
    |
    |__conversations
```

I want to be able to check if a specific ID is located in the `users/"UserID"/friends` folder.

I'm wondering do I need to get the entire contents of `friends` and then iterate through the returned array using Javascript, or is there a Firebase method that will be able to do the check if provided with the ID?

This is my current attempt:

```
function checkIfFriend(receivedFriendId){
    // receivedFriendId is the ID I want to check.
    // globaluid is the currently logged in user's ID (it sits between "users" and "friends")

    // Attempting to check for the presence of receivedFriendId
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + globaluid + '/friends/').child(receivedFriendId).once('value', function(snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log("This ID exists.");
          }else{
            console.log("This ID doesn't exist.");
          }              

    });
}
```

This keeps console.logging "This ID doesn't exist." even though the ID does exist at that location in the database.

I'm wondering is it possible to check for the ID's existence by sending it in the query as above, or do I need to return the entire contents of `friends` and then iterate through the returned list to see if the ID is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
function checkIfFriend(receivedFriendId){

  var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/users/'+globaluid+'/friends/');

      ref.on("child_added", function(child) {

            var IDofFriends = child.val();

                if(IDofFriends == receivedFriendId){
                    console.log("The other user's ID is in the currently signed in user's friend list, they are friends!");
                }else{
                    console.log("This user's ID is NOT in the currently signed in user's friend list, they are NOT friends! So do nothing.");
                }
        });
}
```

Although it has the problem of continuing to run through the array even after it finds a matching ID. I'm not sure how to stop it from running, I've tried `return;` and I've tried setting a flag, but neither seemed to work.

If anyone is able to make the iteration stop once it finds a match, please post it as an answer and I'll accept it instead of mine.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `forEach`, specifically about the part on cancelling iteration/enumeration.  I think it will be helpful.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#forEach

Answer (score 0):

I got this code working perfectly.

```
 var query = firebase.database().ref("Users").orderByKey();
      query.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
var key = childSnapshot.key;
         

          var childData = childSnapshot.child("phoneno").val();

          if (childData == receivedFriendId) {
            // He's a friend
          } else {
            // Do something else
          }

          // Cancel enumeration
          return true;
        });
      });
```